# Any free documentation tool for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm after a Any free documentation tool for Visual Stusio 2010?
Any good ones with sample demo?
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at sandcastle for generating documentation.

Answer (score 1):

[Atomineer Utils](http://www.atomineerutils.com/)
[Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/)

Both have 30-day free trials, neither work for Express Editions, after the free trial ends, the cost is minimal (VAX is 40 for students)